# index.php is not supported after uploading in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm a student and this is my first time uploading my PHP project onto a server. I uploaded it in public_html (my starting page being `index.php`) but when I'm trying to view my website it say "not supported". I have tried `.htaccess` file having the command.

```
### MAIN DEFAULTS
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off
```

but it still displays "not supported".

Comment: What happens if you add it to the URL specifically like this `example.com/index.php`

Comment: Did you buy a free/very cheap hosting package. Maybe PHP is not supported!

Comment: its say not supported sir

Comment: which server/host are you using?

Comment: Are you using `mod_userdir`? This message is usually seen when trying to run Apache's `mod_userdir` module with an unsupported PHP build/run level

Comment: Ok, does it give any more information than that? Dies it say **what** is not supported

Comment: but when i change the index.php into index.html its working but i have php scripts in my index file

Comment: Yea! Sounds very much like PHP is not  available on this hosting package. Check with the Hosts web site. You can probably get PHP included for an EXTRA FEE

Comment: = php is not supported. Again.

Comment: what is mod_userdir sir? ive read that couple of times while solving my problem

Comment: ahhh okay sir ill check it

Comment: Just contact the owners of the server/hosting company and explain the issue for them. That will probably be way easier than it would be for us to guess what's happening (since we don't know anything about the server you're using).

Comment: okay sir. btw im using cpanel sir

Comment: You could try removing the `.htaccess` file entirely. If your host supports PHP, then it will work without that.